# запись в файлы Lua

Tags: lua

как записать в конец файла?

```
file:write()
```

просто заменяет текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_file_io.htm), вам нужно *открыть* файл в режиме дополнения.

Пример оттуда:

```
-- Opens a file in append mode
file = io.open("test.lua", "a")

-- appends a word test to the last line of the file
file:write("--test")

-- closes the open file
file:close()
```